# Format Locale DateTime in PHP

Tags: php

I try to convert a locale Date to other format. Here is the Date I have Понедельник, 16 марта . In format: Day of week, Day of month Month ; and I want to format it like this 16-03-2015. Here is what i've tried so far:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
$formatted_time = date_create_from_format('D, j F', $dateToConvert);
echo date('d-m-Y', $formatted_time);  // outputs 01-01-1970
```

Other method:

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
    $formatted_time = strftime('%A, %d %B', strtotime($dateToConvert));
    //$formatetd_time - Четверг, 01 Январь
    $ret['Day'] = date('d-m-Y', $formatted_time);
```

That cause a warning `PHP Warning:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`

Comment: Did you try this `print_r( date_parse_from_format("F j Y", $dateToConvert) );`

Comment: `Понедельник` this means `Monday`.For the full name of day need to use `I`.Could you try like this `date_create_from_format('I,j F', $dateToConvert);`

Comment: stil does not work. this function return empty value